# Handling Try Catch and Transaction Rollback/Commit in distributed environment

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know the best way to handle transaction rollback/commit and exception handling when we are working on distributed servers.

Scenario is like below:

```
Server1.StroredProcude1
Begin Transaction
Try

--Some insertion here
Server2.StoredProcedure
Commit Transaction
Catch
Rollback Transaction
RETURN @Msg = a user friendly message
End
```

In stored procedure of **Server2** I am also doing some insertion.

1. Should I have to use try catch in **Server2** stored procedure as well or it will be catch in **Server1** itself.
2. I am using 'Distributed Transaction' keyword in **Server1** Stored procedure so is it enough to commit/rollback transactions in both server  or I have to implement the transaction related stuff in **server2** stored procedure as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See here for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188386.aspx

> The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine executing the BEGIN
>   DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION statement is the transaction originator and
>   controls the completion of the transaction. When a subsequent COMMIT
>   TRANSACTION or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is issued for the
>   session, the controlling instance requests that MS DTC manage the
>   completion of the distributed transaction across all of the instances
>   involved.